# Paste variable into regexp

Tags: c#, regex

Help to paste the variable `zone` into regexp pattern. It seems to me I have tried all possible variants... Always error appears!!
 (here instead the static string UntrustGn)

```
            List<string> zones = new List<string>
            { "UntrustGi",
                "DMZPub",
                "DMZMMS", 
                "DmzGi", 
                "TrustGi", 
                "TrustGn", 
                "DmzGn", 
                "UntrustGn",
                "DMZLOM" };


            foreach (string zone in zones)
            {
                string patternZone = @"set address ""(UntrustGn)"" ("".*"") ([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)";
```

Comment: [How to stick strings together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.Format`, like this:

```
foreach (string zone in zones) {
    string patternZone = string.Format(@"set address ""{0}"" ("".*"") ([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)", zone);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that this is the correct answer. But for some reason, my regexp pattern evaluates only first Item of List (here UntrustGi).But this is not related to my question directly...

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
foreach(string zone in zones)
{
   string ptternZone = string.Format(@"set address ""{0}"" ("".*"") ([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)( [0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)", zone);
}
```

The above uses `string.Format` method.